# React - fetching the data before the render (best solution)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, serverside-javascript

So, I have an app that user can choose several settings in. Like number format or a currency that will be displayed by default.

For that there is a special API endpoint `/settings` that I get the values from.

The whole app is rendered on the server side when the user reloads the page. I fire the settings fetch as soon as possible (in the `componentWillMount` of the top level component), but there is sometimes a blink/ delay.

**Possible solutions:**

1. First solution is to fetch the settings when the user loads the app for the first time, and save it in the `localStorage` if it's available. Downside is that the numbers/ currencies still can be different than those in the settings when the app is loaded for the first time.
2. Second solution would be to fetch the data before the application is rendered on the server side, and inject this data somewhere into script tag (like a `window.userSettings = { ...settings }`). It might extend the reload loading time a bit, but the settings will be as the user set them.

Is there any other solution to such a problem? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: The `localStorage` solution could be appropriate but not for the first time the user visits your app. So I would suggest to set your state in `componentWillMount ` with a default state that get the data in the storage. Once I'll place the request in the `componentDidMount` so it will avoid the blink delay

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this solution may help you.

**step 1**: Perform API call in `componentWillMount` and also, check for error. Assign two state one for `currencies` and one for `error`, if possible another one for `loading`
**Step 2**: Assign `localStorage` using your state in `componnetDidMount`
**Step 3**: Then, under your render method, check for both `error state` and `localStorage`

Sample snippet in given below

```
class App extends Component{

  custructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      currency_number: '',
      error: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    //perform fetch api and assign the state with the received items
    // check for error, if so then setState({error: true})
  }

  ComponentDidMount(){
    localStorage.setItem('currency', JSON.stringify(this.state.currency_number))
  }

  render(){
    const currency =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currency'))
    if (this.state.error) {
      return(
        <div>
          { currency }
        </div>

      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve the problem that I do not have the setting when the app is loaded